# Wordpress get_template_part , can't get it to work?

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't get it, I have in my custom wp template:

single-usedcar_model-reader_review.php,

single-usedcar_model-gallery.php

but for some reason

> get_template_part('single-usedcar_model', "gallery");

works everytime and includes it correctly.

While I just get an error when I try to do the same with reader_review. Do I need to define something special to include those files or what?

Error I'm getting is:

```
This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?
```

> object(WP_Query)#809 (46) {   ["query_vars"]=>   array(55) {
>       ["attachment"]=>
>       string(14) "reader_reviews"
>       ["error"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["m"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["p"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["post_parent"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["subpost"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["subpost_id"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["attachment_id"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["name"]=>
>       string(14) "reader_reviews"
>       ["static"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["pagename"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["page_id"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["second"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["minute"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["hour"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["day"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["monthnum"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["year"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["w"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["category_name"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["tag"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["cat"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["tag_id"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["author_name"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["feed"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["tb"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["paged"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["comments_popup"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["meta_key"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["meta_value"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["preview"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["s"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["sentence"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["fields"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["category_*in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["category*_not_in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["category_*and"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["post*_in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["post__not_in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["tag_*in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["tag*_not_in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["tag__and"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["tag_slug__in"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["tag_slug__and"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=>
>       bool(false)
>       ["suppress_filters"]=>
>       bool(false)
>       ["cache_results"]=>
>       bool(true)
>       ["update_post_term_cache"]=>
>       bool(true)
>       ["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
>       bool(true)
>       ["post_type"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["posts_per_page"]=>
>       int(1)
>       ["nopaging"]=>
>       bool(false)
>       ["comments_per_page"]=>
>       string(2) "50"
>       ["no_found_rows"]=>
>       bool(false)
>       ["order"]=>
>       string(4) "DESC"   }   ["tax_query"]=>   NULL   ["meta_query"]=>   object(WP_Meta_Query)#551 (2) {
>       ["queries"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["relation"]=>
>       NULL   }   ["post_count"]=>   int(0)   ["current_post"]=>   int(-1)   ["in_the_loop"]=>   bool(false)   ["comment_count"]=>
>   int(0)   ["current_comment"]=>   int(-1)   ["found_posts"]=>   int(0) 
>   ["max_num_pages"]=>   int(0)   ["max_num_comment_pages"]=>   int(0)
>   ["is_single"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_preview"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_page"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_archive"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_date"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_year"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_month"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_day"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_time"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_author"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_category"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_tag"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_tax"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_search"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_feed"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_comment_feed"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_trackback"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_home"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_404"]=>   bool(true)   ["is_comments_popup"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_paged"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_admin"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_attachment"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_singular"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_robots"]=>   bool(false)   ["is_posts_page"]=>   bool(false)
>   ["is_post_type_archive"]=>   bool(false)   ["query_vars_hash"]=>
>   string(32) "6fd8021e4727db18aa48074428ae7597"
>   ["query_vars_changed"]=>   bool(false)   ["thumbnails_cached"]=>
>   bool(false)   ["query"]=>   array(1) {
>       ["attachment"]=>
>       string(14) "reader_reviews"   }   ["request"]=>   string(160) "SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name
>   = 'reader_reviews' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC "   ["posts"]=>   &array(0) {   }
>   ["queried_object"]=>   NULL   ["queried_object_id"]=>   int(0) }

Comment: No you don't have to define anything else ....Can we see the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please don't show the code which works, show the code which doesn't work - and maybe the errors which occur. Other than that, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part has a few good examples how to work with this function.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with `get_template_part` since it will not output error like this. Please add your template sources.